How to terminate a call when 1 device decline in forking Linphone API?
I'm working on an android application using Linphone API https://download.linphone.org/releases/docs/liblinphone/latest/java/
I already test forking call by login 1 account into 2 different Linphone apps (A and B). When another (C) makes a call to this account, both of them will ring. If I accept A or B, then the other will terminate and the Call.Status is AcceptedElsewhere. But if I want to decline, I have to decline on both devices. Now I want my application just need to decline on only 1 device then other devices will automatically stop ringing.
My code when clicking decline button:
call.decline(Reason.DoNotDisturb);

Then the Call.Status will be DeclinedElsewhere and the SIP status code is 600, but the problem is when I decline on device A, I got the Call.Status is DeclinedElsewhere, but device B doesn't update the Status, it's still Aborted. So I don't know how to make device B can update the Status based on device A.
Thanks a lot!
P/s: Sorry if my English level may make you feel confused in some places.
